# How to reference/name specific part of a shape?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want to reference a specific part of a shape. For example: From Best Apple to Basket 1, instead of apple_node to Basket 1.
The below image will better explain what I wish to achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qWec.jpg

This is my graphviz code and what I have achieved so far:

```
digraph fruits {

    node [shape=record]


    apple_node [label="Apple | {{Best Apple} | {Worst Apple}}"];
    banana_node [label="Banana | {{Best Banana} | {Worst Banana}}"];

    basket1_node [label="basket1|{Colour 10 | Seeds 10}"];
    basket2_node [label="basket2|{Colour 10 | Seeds 10}"];

    apple_node -> basket1_node;
    banana_node -> basket2_node;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using **record-based nodes**, you can add *field id*'s to the label and use them as *portnames* which indicate where to attach an edge to (see also the [official documentation about record-based nodes](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/shapes.html#record)).

Example:

```
examplenode [shape=record; label="<fieldid1> one|<fieldid2> two"];
examplenode:fieldid1 -> othernode;
```

Your apple-banana example:

```
digraph fruits {
    node [shape=record]

    apple_node [label="Apple | {{<bestapple>Best Apple} | {<worstapple>Worst Apple}}"];
    banana_node [label="Banana | {{Best Banana} | {<worstbanana>Worst Banana}}"];

    basket1_node [label="basket1|{Colour 10 | Seeds 10}"];
    basket2_node [label="basket2|{Colour 10 | Seeds 10}"];

    apple_node:bestapple -> basket1_node;
    apple_node:worstapple -> basket1_node;
    banana_node:worstbanana -> basket2_node;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.